# textblock does not fill mobile phone window

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have below code

```
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Loaded="LayoutRoot_Loaded">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" FontWeight="Bold" Padding="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0" Text="فرآن کریم"/>


        <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" Grid.Row="1" Padding="0,0,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AlternateRowConverter}}" Tap="pQuranAya_Tap">
                        <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Aya}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="50" Padding="20,0,0,20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Tap="TextBlock_Tap" />
                        <StackPanel Background="Black"  />
                        <TextBlock Width="Auto" Text="{Binding AyaTranslation}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="35" Padding="20,0,0,20" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I want textblock should be always in window size, but its text size. How can I make it to fill the window size?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<TextBlock Width="Auto"` and add `<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`. After that, your textblock will fit the parent container (window, grid, stackpanel).

Comment: Thanks for reply, It doesn't help, I set the properties for listbox, stackpanel and textblock, but didn't work :(

Comment: Set the same property to `<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"`

Comment: Thanks, It doesn't help either, I don't know what could be issue with this?

Comment: Are you trying to do it with textblock in ListBox? You should add this property to ListBox, StackPanel and textboxes in this case. And remove "Auto".

Comment: I add the same property to all controls (listbox, grid, textblock, stackpanel), but didn't help.

Comment: Yep, doesn't work in listbox. Set the exact width here: ` <DataTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="480" ...`

Comment: Thanks, this is static, if we change mobile into landscape or mobile display changes, then we are in trouble :(

Comment: Change width at the landscape change event.

Comment: Though It's a solution, but I am afraid if phone resolution changes.

Comment: Phone will scale this value. This list will looks the same on 480p device, 720p and 1080p devices. Just test it in the emulators. Additionally, you can use `<ViewBox>`.

Comment: Thanks, I would remember landscape event.

Answer (score 0):

Remove Padding="20,0,0,20" And Margin (if You have in that Code )

Comment: Thanks, Though I need the padding, I removed it and it didn't help as well.

Comment: Margin does not help (I set margin for grid, listbox, stackpanel and textblock)