# Listpicker text-alignment to the right

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, listpicker

I have the follwing listpicker

```
<toolkit:ListPicker  ItemsSource="{Binding title}" Name="titlePicker" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-50,50,0" Background="White" Foreground="#FFDA3434"  Canvas.ZIndex="10"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
```

that contains 3 items and i would like them to align right, but for some reason i can't find the option to align the text, what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in the ListPickerItemTemplate. Add Template to the page resources (or app resources)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerItemTemplate">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
       </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

and assign template to the picker:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker  
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerItemTemplate}" 
   FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListPickerFullModeItemTemplate}" 
...
```

Comment: im using ItemsSource="{Binding title}" that is a List<string> object, What would i set in these fields Text="{Binding ItemName}" on your code?

Comment: Use `Text="{Binding}"`.

Comment: hmm, the items show, but they are still align to the left :\
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2ms1u11.jpg like so

Comment: Add background color, I think that your items have no size at right to align. You should add some width to the item too. Here [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942866/textblock-does-not-fill-mobile-phone-window/20943211#20943211) described.

Comment: Oh besides the width, i had to add TextAlignment="Right" on the texblocks inside the DataTemplate, its working now, thanks